# adding conda environment via cmd line to jupyter doesn't work

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda, osmnx

Trying to get OSMnx into jupyter conda environment.
But conda environment not set correctly.

On command line:

1. Created conda environment using OSMnx installation steps
2. I cloned the environment to rename it 'realestate'
3. Added realestate to Jupyter:

```
> conda activate realestate
> conda install -c anaconda ipykernel
> python -m ipykernel install --user --name=realestate
> which python
/opt/anaconda3/envs/realestate/bin/python
```

On Jupyter the realestate environment shows up... but when I run

```
!which python
```

I get

```
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I've created some conda environments inside of Jupyter(Conda) and they show up as

```
Python [conda env: otherenv]
```

that then produces right path

```
!which python
/opt/anaconda3/envs/otherenv/bin/python
```

What am I missing?

PS. OSMnx install is not a simple conda install

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it sounds like you're trying to have OSMnx, Jupyter, and all the packages in the anaconda metapackage installed together in a single conda environment. If so, just create the conda environment with all those packages in one line, then install the ipython kernelspec in it:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n realestate --strict-channel-priority osmnx anaconda jupyter
conda activate realestate
python -m ipykernel install --sys-prefix --name realestate --display-name "Python (realestate)"
jupyter kernelspec list
```