# MacOS: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osmnx'

Tags: python, macos, conda, osmnx

I am trying to get `osmnx` to work on my Macbook. I have installed it using

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

and I am able to type

```
conda activate ox
```

to activate the environment. However, when running the code, I always get the error message

```
import osmnx as ox
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osmnx'
```

I feel like I have tried everything there is on this topic in other questions, but it seems like the answers maybe only work on Windows? I am totally new to all of this, so maybe someone can help me...

Comment: How are you running the code? Python interpreter? Jupyter?

Comment: If Jupyter, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63317989/7321942

Comment: I am using VSC an running a condo-based python interpreter using Python 3.8.8

Answer (score 0):

You have created a new environment `ox` but the python interpreter cannot find the package in the environment path.

You can check if your desired package is installed by running `conda list` after activating the environment in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did as you said, and `osmnx                     1.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge` is listed in the long output list after running `conda list`. To my understanding this means that the package should be there...

Comment: Can you run `import sys  
print(sys.path)`and check if the python path points to the conda environment? @lavarsovie

Comment: I am not sure if I did it correctly, I did run exactly what you wrote in the terminal after activating the environment and I got this error: `zsh: unknown file attribute: y`

Comment: My bad, should've mentioned running it inside a python terminal. After activating the environment, run `python` to initialize a python terminal and then run `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Ah sorry, got it now...among others I get a path that points to some .egg file in my python3.8/site-packages directory

Comment: These are the paths: ['', '/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python39.zip', '/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.9', '/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

I looked for a folder named osmnx in my anaconda-directory and as a result I get two such folders, but none of them are located in the paths that I get when running the `import sys...` command in python.. maybe that is the problem

Comment: Yea I'd try reinstalling the package using conda/pip and verifying if it installs in your environment.